# How to save data in room with coroutines in java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have response from backend in java file:

this is kotlin file

```
class ResponseData {
    val data: List<DataRoom>? = null
    }
```

this is my code in java, saving response

```
                repo.getValue().saveDataToRoom(response.body().getData());
```

saveDataToRoom

```
            GlobalScope.future {
insertAllDataUseCase.build(data)
}
```

```
class InsertAllDataUseCase (private val dataDao: DataDao):
BaseUseCase<List<DataRoom>, Unit>() {
    override suspend fun create(params: List<DataRoom>) {
        dataDao.setNewDataListWithDelete(params)
    }
}
```

dao

```
    @Transaction
    open suspend fun setNewDataListWithDelete(datas: List<DataRoom>) {
        deleteAllData()
        insertAllData(data)
    }

    @Query("DELETE FROM data")
    abstract suspend fun deleteAllData()

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract suspend fun insertAllData(dataItems:List<DataRoom>)
```

It doesn't work, it doesn't save there. I check with getting the data, checking App Inspection, it is just empty. As well I can log response from backend, it works. Why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `abstract` and the `open`, your DAO is an `interface`, right? If not, that might be the issue, but I don't see any problem with your `@Transaction` there. Check this [example](https://github.com/android/trackr/blob/9b7c22d6e7b2782959389ed115730efcfcddc790/shared/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackr/db/dao/TaskDao.kt#L185).

Also, what's the context behind the usage of `GlobalScope.future`? I think you should be using `GlobalScope.launch`, but even so, if you are doing this in a `ViewModel` I would recommend that you use the *actual* correct way that is `viewModelScope.launch {...`

Comment: It was problem with json, not exact data... my mistake didn't check it after refactoring from realm. GlobalScope.launch gives crash, because I call this method from java file where coroutines don't work. workaround is to use 'CompletableFuture'. Now finally works!